# extract word from file using information from a subset of the file (multiple steps)

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pcregrep

I have two large files that look like the following:

File 1:

```
NW_006502347.1 316684
NW_006527876.1 351
NW_006502151.1 27628
NW_006526579.1 232
NW_006525259.1 132
NW_006501641.1 437014
NW_006525259.1 378
NW_006523082.1 215
NW_006522424.1 153
NW_006522101.1 815
NW_006521985.1 505
NW_006521985.1 527
NW_006521722.1 920
NW_006521525.1 73
NW_006521432.1 258
NW_006521302.1 938
NW_006521272.1 585
NW_006521272.1 745
NW_006521038.1 202
NW_006519846.1 1528
NW_006519837.1 10215
```

File 2:

```
NW_006502347.1  Gnomon  CDS   305319  305340   .  +  0  ID=cds43608  Parent=rna48098  Dbxref=GeneID:102908761,Genbank:XP_006997436.2  Name=XP_006997436.2  gbkey=CDS  gene=LOC102908761  partial=true  product=histone deacetylase 4-like  protein_id=XP_006997436.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  gene  6936    115174   .  -  .  ID=gene0                      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816  Name=Efl1  gbkey=Gene  gene=Efl1  gene_biotype=protein_coding  partial=true  start_range=.,6936
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  mRNA  6936    115174   .  -  .  ID=rna0      Parent=gene0     Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  Name=XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 5 mRNAs%2C 7 Proteins%2C and 99%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments%2C including 16 samples with support for all annotated introns  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  start_range=.,6936  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  exon  115095  115174   .  -  .  ID=id1       Parent=rna0      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  exon  114246  114355   .  -  .  ID=id2       Parent=rna0      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006502347.1  Gnomon  mRNA  272091  477077   .  +  .  ID=rna48098  Parent=gene26399 Dbxref=GeneID:102908761,Genbank:XM_006997374.2  Name=XM_006997374.2  end_range=477077,.  gbkey=mRNA  gene=LOC102908761  model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 1 mRNA%2C and 90%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments  partial=true  product=histone deacetylase 4-like  transcript_id=XM_006997374.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  exon  92339   92472    .  -  .  ID=id5       Parent=rna0      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  exon  90969   91106    .  -  .  ID=id6       Parent=rna0      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006501037.1  Gnomon  exon  89261   89475    .  -  .  ID=id7       Parent=rna0      Dbxref=GeneID:102922816,Genbank:XM_006970114.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Efl1  partial=true  product=elongation factor like GTPase 1  transcript_id=XM_006970114.2
NW_006502151.1  Gnomon  exon  26099   27657    .  -  .  ID=id586652  Parent=rna47002  Dbxref=GeneID:102918658,Genbank:XM_006996663.2  gbkey=mRNA  gene=Rftn1  product=raftlin%2C lipid raft linker 1  transcript_id=XM_006996663.2
NW_006501641.1  Gnomon  mRNA  393496  438556   .  +  .  ID=rna40001  Parent=gene21212 Dbxref=GeneID:102913870,Genbank:XM_015986269.1  Name=XM_015986269.1  gbkey=mRNA  gene=LOC102913870  model_evidence=Supporting evidence includes similarity to: 9 mRNAs%2C 5 Proteins%2C and 81%25 coverage of the annotated genomic feature by RNAseq alignments  product=transmembrane protein 189  transcript_id=XM_015986269.1
NW_006501053.1  Gnomon  exon  5104713 5104872  .  +  .  ID=id45206   Parent=rna3590   Dbxref=GeneID:102916769,Genbank:XR_001580019.1  gbkey=misc_RNA  gene=Mycbpap  product=MYCBP associated protein%2C transcript variant X4  transcript_id=XR_001580019.1
NW_006501053.1  Gnomon  exon  5104959 5105062  .  +  .  ID=id45207   Parent=rna3590   Dbxref=GeneID:102916769,Genbank:XR_001580019.1  gbkey=misc_RNA  gene=Mycbpap  product=MYCBP associated protein%2C transcript variant X4  transcript_id=XR_001580019.1
NW_006501053.1  Gnomon  exon  5105698 5105881  .  +  .  ID=id45208   Parent=rna3590   Dbxref=GeneID:102916769,Genbank:XR_001580019.1  gbkey=misc_RNA  gene=Mycbpap  product=MYCBP associated protein%2C transcript variant X4  transcript_id=XR_001580019.1
NW_006501053.1  Gnomon  exon  5106131 5106246  .  +  .  ID=id45209   Parent=rna3590   Dbxref=GeneID:102916769,Genbank:XR_001580019.1  gbkey=misc_RNA  gene=Mycbpap  product=MYCBP associated protein%2C transcript variant X4  transcript_id=XR_001580019.1
```

I want to use information from file 1 to extract the word following "gene=" under column 13 or 14 (e.g. "Efl1").
More specifically, I want to:

**Step 1)** Compare labels from column 1 from file 1 (e.g. NW_006527876.1) to labels of column 1 from file 2, extract all the rows for which column 1 (file 2) matches column 1 of file 1.

As you can see, the labels of column 1 (file 2) repeat, so there will be multiple matches for every label of file 1.

Column 4 and 5 of file 2 represent an interval, with column 4 being the start and column 5 the end of the interval. Column 2 of file 1 represent numbers in between these intervals.

**Step 2)**  Of the rows isolated from step 1, extract the rows for which the number under column 2 (file 1) lies between the interval denoted by column 4 and 5 of file 2.

This is far beyond what I know but below is an idea of how the commands might look like.

```
awk '{ print $1 }' file 1 |  
awk `$4 *(file2)* < $2 *(file1)*' | awk '$5 *(file2)* > $2 *(file1)*' > output.tsv
```

The output should have rows with unique labels under column 1.

**Step 3)** From the output.tsv file created above, I'd like to extract the word that follows the equal sign in "gene=" under either column 13 or 14 (see below), such that I end up with a file just with the words following the equal sign.

**Final output file** (based this example):

```
LOC102908761
Rftn1
LOC102913870
```

ANSWER:

```
while read -r id pos; do awk -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" '$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5 { if (gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) !~ /\s/) print gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1); }' < file2.txt; done <file1.txt > gene_hits.txt
```

Next to get rid of replicates (same locus in multiple intervals) while keeping different loci mapped to the same gene, do:

```
perl -ne 'print if ++$k{$_}==1' A_gene_hits.txt > A_genes.txt
```

Comment: Please post a minimal working example for the input files, as well as your expected output. With your current example, if I understand correctly, there are no matches, so there should be no output.

Comment: `sort` and `join` would be a possible start ...

Comment: I've added matches to show what the output file would look like.

Comment: Hang on, so `NW_006502347.1` matches twice. Wouldn't you expect two outputs for that? Or do you only want the first match? Also, please tag me with `@Sparhawk` so I am notified of replies.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes I only want one NW_006502347.1 because in the second number from list 1 (316684) falls within the interval  272091  477077, but not between 305319  305340. There will be many multiple hits based on the first column (NW_#) but the second number from list 1 should fall between the interval of only one of those hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have white space as a delimiter:

```
$ while read -r id pos; do awk -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" '$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5 { print gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) }' <file2; done <file1
LOC102908761
Rftn1
LOC102913870
```

#### Explanation

- `while read -r id pos; do FOO; done <file1`: this reads `file1` line by line, and places the first field (e.g. `NW_006502347.1`) into the shell variable `$id`, and the second field (e.g. `316684`) into the shell variable `$pos`. It then runs `FOO` for each line.
- `awk -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" 'BAR' <file2`: for each line of `file1`, we will run an `awk` command that will run `BAR`. This will search `file2` for the matching parts. We need to tell this `awk` script the two "external" variables from the shell. i.e. the awk variable `id` is assigned the same value as the shell variable `$id`, and the same for the awk variable `pos` and the shell variable `$pos`.
- `$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5`: this is the "conditional" part of the `awk` script. If these conditions are met, then the following commands will run. Here, we are checking if the first field `$1` of `file2` is the same as the `id` from the current line of `file1`, AND if `pos` is between the 4th `$4` and 5th `$5` fields of `file2`.
- `{ print gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) }`: if the above conditions are met, then this code will run. We want to make a substitution with `gensub` first. This searches for `gene=` followed by an alphanumeric string of any length `([A-Za-z0-9]*)`. This alphanumeric string is `(` captured `)` by the parens. We will also "search" for all characters before and after `.*` the full string `gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*)`. Hence, this "searches" for the entire line, which is replaced with the (first and only) capturing group `"\\1"`, i.e. the alphanumeric string after `gene=`. The final `1` means to replace the first occurance, although this doesn't make much sense, as I assume there will only be one match of `gene=` per line.

## Tab-delimited version

I prefer using tab-delimited files in general, especially for what I assume is a GFF/GTF file. This allows differentiating between spaces, especially in the 9th field.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r id pos; do awk -F'\t' -v id="$id" -v pos="$pos" '$1 == id && pos > $4 && pos < $5 { print gensub(/.*gene=([A-Za-z0-9]*).*/, "\\1", 1) }' <file2.tsv ; done <file1.tsv
```

The modifications to the script are explicitly splitting shell lines on tabs with `IFS=$'\t'`, and `awk` lines with `-F'\t'`.

Comment: Thanks, @Sparhawk!. The code you provided was printing the entire row for hits that matched the < and > condition. However, I wasn't clear enough in my questino, I only wanted the gene name as the output. My colleague modified your code to get it to work as I intended.

Comment: @Age87 Huh… it shouldn't have done that. I did understand the requirements. Also, I pasted the output in the first code block. How did you modify the code? I'd be interested as to what was changed.

Comment: I included the code above in my question under "Answer".